# Is this a function?

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem

Given a list of `(key, value)` pairs, determine whether it represents a function, meaning that each key maps to a consistent value. In other words, whenever two entries have equal keys, they must also have equal values. Repeated entries are OK.

For example:

```python
# Not a function: 3 maps to both 1 and 6
[(3,1), (2,5), (3,6)]

# Function: It's OK that (3,5) is listed twice, and that both 6 and 4 both map to 4
[(3,5), (3,5), (6,4), (4,4)]
```

**Input:** An ordered sequence of `(key, value)` pairs using digits 1 to 9. You may not require a particular ordering.  You may alternatively take the key list and value list as separate inputs.

**Output:** A consistent value for functions, and a different consistent value for non-functions.

**Test cases:** The first 5 inputs are functions, the last 5 are not.

```python
[(3, 5), (3, 5), (6, 4), (4, 4)]
[(9, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4)]
[]
[(1, 1)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1)]

[(3, 1), (2, 5), (3, 6)]
[(1, 2), (2, 1), (5, 2), (1, 2), (2, 5)]
[(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 9)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)]
[(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)]
```

Here they are as two lists of inputs:

```python
[[(3, 5), (3, 5), (6, 4), (4, 4)], [(9, 4), (1, 4), (2, 4)], [], [(1, 1)], [(1, 2), (2, 1)]]
[[(3, 1), (2, 5), (3, 6)], [(1, 2), (2, 1), (5, 2), (1, 2), (2, 5)], [(8, 8), (8, 8), (8, 9), (8, 9)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4)], [(1, 2), (1, 3), (2, 3), (2, 4)]]
```

---

**Leaderboard:**

```js
var QUESTION_ID=118960,OVERRIDE_USER=20260;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/118960/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Comment: surjective function?

Comment: @Poke It doesn't have to be surjective.

Comment: Could the input be two lists of equal length, one for keys one for values?

Comment: @HelkaHomba Yes.

Comment: What is the required data range for the values?

Comment: Can the input be a flattened array like `[key,value,key,value]`?

Comment: @Chris Sure, go for it.

Comment: @MatteoItalia Numbers 1 to 9.

Comment: Is it OK for the `(key,value)` pairs to be reversed, as in `(value,key)`? I can shave a few bytes off my answer if so.

Comment: @ymbirtt Yes, you can have the pairs be in either order.

Answer (score 38):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 34 bytes

```python
lambda x:len(dict(x))==len(set(x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bZDNCoMwEITvPsXeTCAe/ImokGufoDcrxdYEBLVFU/DtbVbjT6mnLzOTyS5R4jY1ZfuoShizRnakqp@ajJQKgWqQs5j0XctBizwnIQNOGWyMGUTICFkwyElqHd8yWJM5Na5P11Ngc@MUjjrO8G2yzopPOobc6oPPl5sJgwSdA9ONP28Zhtu@p0mwM8JNnXdfdxpcD679R4LnOurVA24PdQfLX2XLHUVQ0L1xKZvhr6JOKtMX)

Creates a Dictionary and a Set from the input and compare their lengths.
Dictionaries can't have duplicated keys, so all the illegal (and repeated) values are removed.

Comment: Python 3, 30 bytes: `lambda x:not dict(x).items()^x`

Comment: `lambda x:len({**x})==len({*x})`

Answer (score 22):

### Haskell, 36 bytes

```
f x=and[v==n|(k,v)<-x,(m,n)<-x,k==m]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/haskell#dY/NCoMwEITvfYo5eIiwPfgTUTB9keBBEEHEtJQiHvruNombYKHN5dvMzGY3@4hN9WbQq1LmLWZa0/a6kVjI@GJWaun2pZ8MFIb7BfY8npN5IcGINrkBWouCIFNCZEUoHUvHjqBFw0rGzIPjXatmaahy9q3S/Z@XcSrMrX70W0q@n3R5JGtC7ZQTm8ivtyyLuLt3JGcbnh9@J4@t9w8)

Outer (->`(k,v)`) and inner (-> `(m,n)`) loop over the pairs and whenever `k==m`, collect the truth value of `v==n`. Check if all are true.

Comment: You're too quick! :/

Answer (score 20):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>5</s> 4 bytes

```
dhᵐ≠
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@5@S8XDrhEedC/7/j4421jGN1YGSZjomQNIESMYCAA)

Full program. As far as I can tell, the reason that this is beating most other golfing languages is that `≠` is a builtin in Brachylog, whereas most of the other golfing languages need to synthesize it.

### Explanation

```
dhᵐ≠
d     On the list of all unique elements of {the input},
 h    take the first element
  ᵐ     of each of those elements
   ≠  and assert that all those elements are different
```

As a full program, we get `true` if the assertion succeeds, or `false` if it fails.

Answer (score 17):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 5 bytes

I'm pretty happy with this one.

```
{IhM{
       implicit input
    {  removes duplicate pairs
  hM   first element of each pair
{I     checks invariance over deduplication (i.e. checks if no duplicates)
```

[Try it online!](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%7BIhM%7B&input=%5B%283%2C%205%29%2C%20%283%2C%205%29%2C%20%286%2C%204%29%2C%20%284%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%289%2C%204%29%2C%20%281%2C%204%29%2C%20%282%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%201%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%201%29%5D%0A%0A%5B%283%2C%201%29%2C%20%282%2C%205%29%2C%20%283%2C%206%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%201%29%2C%20%285%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%205%29%5D%0A%5B%288%2C%208%29%2C%20%288%2C%208%29%2C%20%288%2C%209%29%2C%20%288%2C%209%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%203%29%2C%20%281%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%203%29%2C%20%282%2C%203%29%2C%20%282%2C%204%29%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%283%2C%205%29%2C%20%283%2C%205%29%2C%20%286%2C%204%29%2C%20%284%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%289%2C%204%29%2C%20%281%2C%204%29%2C%20%282%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%201%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%201%29%5D%0A%5B%283%2C%201%29%2C%20%282%2C%205%29%2C%20%283%2C%206%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%201%29%2C%20%285%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%282%2C%205%29%5D%0A%5B%288%2C%208%29%2C%20%288%2C%208%29%2C%20%288%2C%209%29%2C%20%288%2C%209%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%203%29%2C%20%281%2C%204%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C%202%29%2C%20%281%2C%203%29%2C%20%282%2C%203%29%2C%20%282%2C%204%29%5D&debug=0)

Answer (score 10):

### [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), 25 bytes

```
1`({\d+,)(\d+}).*\1(?!\2)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/retina#VY49DoAgDIV3buFgAtqYlB8jk6OXYHDwFoSzY1sg0eXL63v9m/V1V7x1Ts8KRhOL2ZaE@pySNbVmB6FA5w6e6IkqR9EotOwoKrAwrVisHZF1W7H/UshB9HACpQccpAdj55hCcP2kollOo2xur4TP9dZpO315AQ)

Input format is `{k,v},{k,v},...`. Prints `0` for functions and `1` for non-functions. I could save two bytes by using linefeeds instead of the commas in the input format, but that's messed up.

Comment: I believe it qualifies as "seriously wack," at least from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 10):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 13 bytes

```
¬{⊇Ċhᵐ=∧Ċtᵐ≠}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brachylog2#@39oTfWjrvYjXRkPt06wfdSx/EhXCZD1qHNB7f//0dHGOqaxOlDSTMcESJoAydj/AA)

#### Explanation

```
¬{          }      It is impossible...
  ⊇Ċ               ...to find a subset of length 2 of the input...
   Ċhᵐ=            ...for which both elements have the same head...
       ∧           ...and...
        Ċtᵐ≠       ...have different tails.
```

Comment: Can you explain how `Ċhᵐ=` and `Ċtᵐ≠` work?

Comment: @CalculatorFeline Uppercase letters are variable names. `Ċ` is a special variable called *Couple* which is always preconstrained to be a list of two elements. `ᵐ` is a metapredicate which applies the immediatly previous predicate (`h - head` or `t - tail` here) to each element of the input (here, `Ċ`). `=` and `≠` simpl check that their input contains all equal/all different elements.

Answer (score 7):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>11</s> <s>9</s> 7 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to *kalsowerus*.

```
Ùø¬DÙQ,
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3945uEdh9a4HJ4ZqPP/f3S0sY6CaayOApw201EwAdEmIDoWAA)

**Explanation**

```
Ù           # remove duplicates
 ø          # zip
  ¬         # get the first element of the list (keys)
   D        # duplicate list of keys
    Ù       # remove duplicates in the copy
     Q      # compare for equality
      ,     # explicitly print result
```

Comment: @Riley: Yep. I'm still quite happy that the special case only ended up a third of the program :P

Comment: I think you could save 3 bytes by replacing `\`\)^` with head (`¬`): [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3945uEdh9a4HJ4Z@P9/dLShjoJRrI4CiDYG0UYI2iQ2FgA "05AB1E – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @kalsowerus: Unfortunately that breaks for the special case of `[]` :(

Comment: @Enigma Oh it worked because when testing I still had a leftover `,` at the end. Add that and then it somehow works with `[]`.

Comment: Updated [TIO](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3945uEdh9a4HJ4ZqPP/f3QsAA "05AB1E – TIO Nexus")

Comment: @kalsowerus: It does indeed work with an explicit print. Nice find :) Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 8 bytes

```
1Z?gs2<A
```

Inputs are: an array with the `value`s, followed by an array with the `key`s.

Output is `1` for function, `0` otherswise.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@28YZ9ebGTj@P9/tKmCqYKJgkksV7SxgrGCGZAFAA). Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#RU1BCsAwCLvvFfmC2pYWBmOwJ@y0UthtD9j/6USFoWI0id6Tru15ed3ncc6ekZGQxtIFgmIoxaaBwNo9KYphyBhSdzEvQ5xTxMiuUNZ1FRUNLZCGacW@kGoo5n@jV8YH).

#### Explanation

`1Z?`

Builds a sparse matrix. Initially all entries contain `0`; and `1` is added to each entry `(i, j)` where `j` and `i` are the input `key`, `value` pairs.

`g`

The matrix is converted to logical; that is, entries exceeding `1` (corresponding to duplicate `key`, `value` pairs) are set to `1`.

`s`

The sum of each column is computed. This is the number of different `value`s for each `key`.

`2<A`

A function will have all such sums less than `2`.

Answer (score 6):

## R, 33 bytes

This is my version for R.  This takes advantage of the `ave` function. I have allowed for empty input by setting defaults on the key and value parameters.  `ave` is producing a mean of the values for each of the keys.  Fortunately this returns the means in the same order as the input values, so a comparison to the input will indicate if there is different values.  Returns `TRUE` if it is a function.

```r
function(k=0,v=0)all(ave(v,k)==v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/r#TY5LDoMwDET3nMSWZkE@oGaRw6CokSoQ3bS5furgAJU3njfjkXOs@bunz@u90xpHlDjysm20lCcVrBxj4ZopkYPDDM9INGGCl5WHZgQY2Ib9HzQNmEN0oBmLBgcttHBHTOpmvmKi7rBIAd18oE8zdQ0I16WMXrn7DW04sRr1Bw)

Answer (score 5):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>45</s> 38 bytes

*Saved 6 bytes thanks to @Neil*

```
a=>a.some(([k,v])=>m[k]-(m[k]=v),m={})
```

Returns `false` or `true` for functions and non-functions, respectively.

This works by constantly subtracting the old value of each function (`m[k]`) and the new one (`m[k]=v`, which also stores the new value). Each time, there are three cases:

- If there was no old value, `m[k]` returns `undefined`. Subtracting anything from `undefined` results in `NaN`, which is falsy.
- If the old value is the same as the new one, `m[k]-v` results in `0`, which is falsy.
- If the old value is different from the new one, `m[k]-v` results in a non-zero integer, which is truthy.

Therefore, we just have to make sure that `m[k]-(m[k]=v)` is never truthy.

Comment: Far too long. Use `a=>!a.some(([x,y])=>m[x]-(m[x]=y),m=[])`.

Comment: @Neil Dang it, I knew there had to be *some* way to utilize `m[k]` being undefined... Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

### Mathematica, 24 bytes

```
UnsameQ@@(#&@@@Union@#)&
```

Explanation: `Union` deletes duplicated pairs, then `#&@@@` gets the first element from each pair (like `First/@` but with fewer bytes). If there is any repetition in these first elements, the pairs don't make a function, which we check with `UnsameQ`.

(This might have the highest density of `@` characters in any program I've written…)

Comment: `@` density=1/4

Answer (score 5):

## [J-uby](http://github.com/cyoce/J-uby), <s>48</s> <s>33</s> <s>25</s> 21 bytes

-3 bytes thanks to Jordan!

```rb
:size*:==%[:to_h,~:|]
```

#### Explanation

```rb
:size*:==%[:to_h,~:|]

# "readable"
(:size * :==) % [:to_h, ~:|]

# transform :% to explicit lambda
->(x){ (:size * :==).(:to_h ^ x, ~:| ^ x)

# apply explicit x to functions
->(x){ (:size * :==).(x.to_h, x|x) }

# expand :* (map over arguments)
->(x){ :==.(:size.(x.to_h), :size.(x|x) }

# simplify symbol calls to method calls
->(x){ x.to_h.size == (x|x).size }

# :| is set union for arrays; x|x just removes duplicates, like :uniq but shorter
->(x){ x.to_h.size == x.uniq.size }
```

## First Approach, 33 bytes

```rb
-[:[]&Hash,:uniq]|:*&:size|:/&:==
```

This one is longer than the equivalent Ruby solution, but it was fun to make.

Attempt of explanation by transforming to Ruby:

```rb
-[:[]&Hash,:uniq]|:*&:size|:/&:==

# "readable"
-[:[] & Hash, :uniq] | (:* & :size) | (:/ & :==)                  

# turn into explicit lambda
->(x){ (:/ & :==) ^ ((:* & :size) ^ (-[:[] & Hash, :uniq] ^ x)) } 

# simplify expressions now that we have an explicit x
->(x){ :== / (:size * [Hash[x], x.uniq]) }                          

# translate to equivalent Ruby code
->(x) { [Hash[x], x.uniq].map(&:size).reduce(:==) }               

# simplify reduce over explicit array
->(x) { Hash[x].size == x.uniq.size }
```

I could save 2 bytes with a newer version by replacing `:uniq` with `~:|`

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 9 bytes

Code:

```
ãü-ʒ¬_}}Ë
```

Explanation:

```
ã            # Cartesian product with itself
 ü-          # Pairwise subtraction
   ʒ  }}     # Filter out elements where the following is not true:
    ¬_       #   Check whether the first digit is 0
        Ë    # Check if all equal
```

Uses the **05AB1E** encoding. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@3948eE9uqcmHVoTX1t7uPv//@hoYx0F01gdBThtpqNgAqJNQHQsAA)

Comment: Getting to show off `ʒ` right away I see :)

Comment: @Emigna Yeah haha :p, but I already found a bug that causes me to use `}}` instead of `}`.

Answer (score 4):

## Bash + coreutils, 17

```bash
sort -u|uniq -dw1
```

Input is given via STDIN.  `key` and `value` are <kbd>Tab</kbd> separated and each pair is newline-delimited.

`sort` removes the duplicate key-value pairs.  `uniq -d` only outputs duplicates, and so outputs the empty string in the case of a function, and a non-empty string otherwise - when there are duplicate keys that map to different values.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus/bash#XZBNDoMgEIXXcIpZdOsC/6Kt6a7d9gwKWGkaSRXTjXe3IxVFSV6YvO8xDPDSwBVKKAq4Pe40IolVSmIao2aPcpupXCZHn6HCPeeOe55wHiPM9@Xmh9hnx@ptFoZsnif1@fN4NsH9Xyd@rnG5jGSLcisvo/xejET2XR5/HXlotWRq3YGRvanVW4Jq8Rcr/AWBr6txyga7vy4gNAVckjd6DZ/h5EoL58tWB8ap152BYBiHVn0gEF82Cd3K6Qc).

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
QḢ€µQ⁼
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/4cMeiR01rHu5c5Plw14L///9HRxvrmMbqQEkzMGmqYxIbCwA)

**Explanation**

```
QḢ€µQ⁼
Q      - Remove duplicate pairs
 Ḣ€    - Retrieve the first element of each pair
   µ   - On the output of what came before..
     ⁼ - Are the following two equal (bit returned)?
    Q  - The output with duplicates removed
       - (implicit) the output.
```

Here is an alternate method, also 6 bytes:

```
QḢ€ṢIẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@x/4cMeiR01rDm0NfNS45////9HRhjoKRrE6CtFGOgqGINoUzjcFUWDpWAA)

Instead of testing with removing duplicate keys, this sorts (`Ṣ`) and checks if the difference between terms (`I`) is all truthy (`Ạ`)

Answer (score 4):

## R, <s>36</s> 33 bytes

```r
function(k,v)any(v[match(k,k)]-v)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBDoMgFET3nOIn3fyfjAtFu@pNGhcEIW2otKlIwulR3L2ZefOvnh4dVb9Hm97fyAFZTCycn6tJ9nXmIHOXpXq2rKFxxyiwPGHCeKKoNrRGhG7k1l8qFFzZyMSFsvnsbruUHj0GDM1soK@vUvUA)

anonymous function; returns `FALSE` for functions and `TRUE` for not.

This <s>is being beaten by</s> is finally tied with [MickyT's answer!](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119045/67312)!

Answer (score 4):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 6 bytes

```
nþ`ḄCȦ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/jelly#@593eF/Cwx0tzieW/T/c/qhpDRC5//8frRAdrWGso2CqqaMAp810FExAtAmIjtVRiNawhIoYQmkjmAxYFihqqAljGUHlgSKxOlxQ4w2hgjBrzLAoB9KmUD6SuClEpYWOggVIBIm2hNMoZgFpY7hTscoYIWigiliuWAA)

#### How it works

```
nþ`ḄCȦ  Main link. Argument: M (n×2 matrix)

nþ`     Construct the table of (a != b, c != d) with (a, b) and (c, d) in M.
   Ḅ    Unbinary; map (0, 0), (0, 1), (1, 0), (1, 1) to 0, 1, 2, 3 (resp.).
    C   Complement; map each resulting integer x to 1 - x.
     Ȧ  All; test if all resulting integers are non-zero.
```

Answer (score 4):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 4 bytes

```
╔♂F═
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/actually#@/9o6pRHM5vcHk2d8P9/tIaxjoKhpo6ChpGOgimIBvLNNGMB)

Explanation:

```
╔♂F═
╔     uniquify (remove duplicate pairs)
 ♂F   take first items in each pair (keys)
   ═  are all of the keys unique?
```

Answer (score 4):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), 11 bytes

```
{r~?r:*'?x}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJxLs6ouqrMvstJSt6+o5eJKc9AwVjC1BmEzBRNrEwUTTYiYobURWNwMzDdUMALyDTUB4EoNpw==)

Port of chunes' factor answer.

### Explanation

```
{r~?r:*'?x}

{         }     /function
        ?x      /distinct values
      *'        /first value of each
    r:          /store in r
 r~?            /is distinct?
```

Comment: -1 byte if you convert it to a train: `~/1?:\*'?:`

Answer (score 3):

## [V](https://github.com/DJMcMayhem/V), 30 bytes

```
Úç^¨.*©î±$/d
ÎwD
ç/HdG
Íî
Ò1lD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/v#@3941uHlcYdW6GkdWnl43aGNKvopXIf7yl24Di/X90hx5zrce3gd1@FJhjku//8bK5hygbCZggkQm3KZKJgAAA)

Outputs `1` for functions and nothing for non-functions.

Answer (score 3):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>19</s> 17 bytes

Saved 2 bytes thanks to Martin Ender

```
0l~$2ew{:.=~!&|}/
```

Outputs `0` for functions and `1` for non-functions.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#q/5vkFOnYpRaXm2lZ1unqFZTq/@/oNbQQOt/dLSxgmmsApQ0UzABkiZAMpYrOtoSzDMEk0YQMZCwoYJhLIQ2AktAeMZAGsSDGGaGpkIh2hTMhomYguUtFCyAPBhpCSUROg0VjKEOQBczgpJAGQA)

**Explanation**

```
0                     e# Push a 0. We need it for later.
 l~                   e# Read and eval a line of input.
   $                  e# Sort it by the keys.
    2ew               e# Get all consecutive pairs of the sorted list.
       {              e# For each pair of pairs:
        :.=           e#  Check if the keys are equal and if the values are equal.
           ~!&        e#  Determine if the keys are equal AND the values are not equal.
              |       e#  OR with 0. If any pair indicates that the input is not a function,
                      e#  this will become 1 (and remain 1), otherwise it will be 0.
               }/     e# (end block)
```

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>95</s> 66 bytes

```r
function(k,v)any(sapply(k,function(x){length(unique(v[k==x]))-1}))
```

*Saved 29 bytes thanks to Jarko Dubbeldam.*

Anonymous function. Outputs `FALSE` if a function and `TRUE` if not (sorry). Takes as arguments a list of keys and a list of values, like so.

```r
> f(c(1,2,5,1,2),c(2,1,2,2,5))
[1] TRUE # not a function
```

Loops through all keys and grabs the length of the set of unique values for that key. If `any` of them are > 1, return `TRUE`.

This is being beaten by [MickyT](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/118960/is-this-a-function/119045#119045)'s answer, and also [Giuseppe](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119006/62105)'s. upvote one of those.

Comment: Why are you creating a dataframe, only to then reference the vectors you just put into that dataframe? `function(k=0,v=0)any(sapply(k,function(x){length(unique(v[k==x]))-1}))` should accomplish the same thing.

Comment: Because I'm still learning! At least one of the other R answers does it more or less like you describe.

Comment: sorry if I came off a bit harsh :) your submission is a bit different to the other R answers, and if you were to cut out the redundant data.frame, you might be able to compare better.

Answer (score 3):

## Mathematica, 35 bytes

```
(l=Length)@Union@#==l@<|Rule@@@#|>&
```

Pure function taking a list of ordered pairs as input and returning `True` or `False`. Exploits the fact that `Union@#` deletes repeated ordered pairs, but `<|Rule@@@#|>` (an association) deletes all but one ordered pair with a particular first element. So we can just compare the `Length`s of the two outputs to check whether the input list is a function.

Answer (score 3):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>16</s> <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```apl
(∪≡⊢)⊃¨∘∪
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#@@/4qG2CxqOOVY86Fz7qWqT5qKv50IpHHTOAIv//OypoPOpqMtZRMNXUQWea6SiYQJkmICYXRLElQtgQwTSCqnjUuwaqDihpqIlgGyEUAoUtDB71blHXVeeCO8AQIY/kFjNcJkCYpghRVAWmMH0WOgoWUGFUpiUyE9MSINMY2Zd4VRihME00AQ)

#### Explanation

```apl
∪             Unique, remove duplicates; (3 5) (3 5) => (3 5)
¨∘            For each element
⊃             Pick the first sub element (3 5) (2 3) => 3 

 ≡            Check whether the arguments (listed below) are the same
  ⊢           The right argument
∪             And the right argument with duplicates removed
```

Prints `0` for false and `1` for true

Comment: Whoa, you're getting really good.

Answer (score 3):

## [brainfuck](https://github.com/TryItOnline/tio-transpilers), 71 bytes

```
,[[-[->>+<<]+>>],>[[->+<<->]<[<<]>]>[-<+>]<<[->+<]+[-<<]>>,]-[--->+<]>.
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/brainfuck#HcvBDQAxCAPBgoBIIfdEbgS5/zKIL88dy@Pd0QFYFQ2gQ/BXgNVCEB1lqnoDTSmGU8d4hDWzc588@V0)

Input is taken as a flat string: for instance, the first test case would be `35356444`.  To get the representation shown in the original question, simply add a total of six commas to the program at the right points.

Output is `U` for functions and `V` for non-functions.

#### Explanation

For any ASCII code point n, f(n) is stored at cell 2n+1.  Cells 2n and 2n+2 are working space, and 0, 2, 4, 6, ... 2n-2 are a trail of breadcrumbs to lead back to cell 0.  When the input is proven not to be a function, f(0) is set to 1 (among various side effects).

```
,                  input first key
[                  start main loop
 [-[->>+<<]+>>]    move to cell 2n, leaving a trail of breadcrumbs
 ,                 input value corresponding to current key
 >[                if key already has a value:
   [->+<<->]<      copy existing value, and compare to new value
   [<<]            if values are different, go to cell -2
   >               go back to cell 2n+1 (or -1 if mismatch)
 ]
 >[-<+>]           move existing value back to cell 2n+1 (NOP if no existing value, move the 1 from cell 0 to cell -1 if mismatch)
 <<[->+<]          copy new value to cell 2n+1 (NOP if there was already a value)
 +[-<<]>>          follow breadcrumbs back to cell 0 (NOP if mismatch)
 ,                 input next key
]                  (if mismatch, cell -2 becomes the next "cell 0", and the next key is also effectively changed by the breadcrumbs left lying around)
-[--->+<]>.        add 85 to cell 1 and output the result
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Desmos](https://desmos.com/calculator), 46 bytes

```
U=L.unique
f(L)=0^{U.length-U.x.unique.length}
```

Function returning 1 for functions and 0 for non-functions.

Equivalent, but slightly longer:

```
f(L)=0^{L.unique.length-L.unique.x.unique.length}
```

[Try it on Desmos!](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/zqk5ac1hwp)

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 28 bytes

```
[ members keys all-unique? ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZC/DsIgEMb3PsW9gCZgbawOjsbFxTgZBySYNLV/5OjQNDw7XlpsaYzyDT@4@447eAhpKu0u5@PpsAWBWEmEWitj2lpnpQFUr0aVUiHtDMIuiroIaHWkFazBBkwg7hn3tKMv9XHmyWf5ycdIdnbm3j/Eg8bMJz4DJH8KO3JxPwAP6ib/hmRnTAN@38uo4/Sg33k@cvDZyF2hUMVdaYRctQji@Vw0ZUZ/vIebK0QNaITMl@4N)

- `members` Get the unique elements
- `keys` Get the keys of an associative array as a sequence
- `all-unique?` Are they all unique?

```
             ! { { 1 2 } { 2 1 } { 5 2 } { 1 2 } { 2 5 } }
members      ! { { 1 2 } { 2 1 } { 5 2 } { 2 5 } }
keys         ! { 1 2 5 2 }
all-unique?  ! f
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), 14 bytes

```
!x=x⊆Dict(x)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=bY8xDoIwFIZ3TvHcXpNqIgiBASZXT2AcipZYQ6pBNB2cHbyCCwur93H1Cl7A1lYk0S5f-_1_XttruzmUgjVNe6iLYXwbqFQ9LuepWNaoiJX3dbGtQICQUHG2KoXkeyQe6KUgBX5kJc54zUY7Vu05CvLNFIxOGSAymhNKYJgBS7P8He8qIetSoq5lMFDE43Jl72vuzzkGFEJCoWNEYWI4MVx4c0ycGDv6LjCZdmPiNr4LrQjMxorP-Oi3qRm6c8-H72JMITaix6Rjf5Jm0D3wX-B_qQv27y8)

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 12 bytes

```
iFFvXu1Z)SdA
```

The input is 2-column matrix, where the first column is key and the second is value.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#S/if6eZWFlFqGKUZnOL43yXkf7SxjoKptQKENNNRMLFWMAGSsVzRlmCOIZg0gggBEZBvCKGMwMIgDlCzIZgDMcgMRd5awRTMhouYAqUtdBQsrBXgpCWEhOsDksYQq9GEjGCkSSwA)

#### Explanation

```
i     % Input: 2-column matrix
FFv   % Postpend a row with two zeros. This handles the empty case
Xu    % Unique rows. This removes duplicate (key, value) pairs
1Z)   % Select first column, that is, key. We need to check if all
      % keys surviving at this point are different
S     % Sort
d     % Consecutive differences
A     % Are all values nonzero?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 38 bytes

```perl6
!*.unique(:as(~*)).repeated(:as(*[0]))
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/nexus/perl6#jVFBbsIwELz7FcsF2cFEJCQRNCri1BdwoxwiMJIlcEJsV6pQ@/XUsYyTAJU4jXdmdtZra8ngKwv3OTp/w5jL6VGLveKlgPdmFIRa8Itm@K2Q@DcgJKxZxQrFDpYJtrMdIY1tXQ9aASOALZ5TSAkFjxmFpMWkxR21nqXjIodxpzmHUSLSnWPnshzxw0Wpnl4gcvbbRbKnUQZTV/f49OZdUFi0XA@XHu/yDM79Qv9ocYeJW0Obj9gwqXJUnQoxfM/Jw4Y5Opb10DRdwScXlVZwNTO5hJ6IrWAmbmrNKNgK/fiMwdu9lPNRnGQX1PwB)

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - <s>9</s> 8 bytes

```
ql.d{Ql{
```

[Try it](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=ql.d%7BQl%7B&input=%5B%283%2C+5%29%2C+%283%2C+5%29%2C+%286%2C+4%29%2C+%284%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%289%2C+4%29%2C+%281%2C+4%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+1%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+1%29%5D%0A%5B%283%2C+1%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%2C+%283%2C+6%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+1%29%2C+%285%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%5D%0A%5B%288%2C+8%29%2C+%288%2C+8%29%2C+%288%2C+9%29%2C+%288%2C+9%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+3%29%2C+%281%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+3%29%2C+%282%2C+3%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=%5B%283%2C+5%29%2C+%283%2C+5%29%2C+%286%2C+4%29%2C+%284%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%289%2C+4%29%2C+%281%2C+4%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+1%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+1%29%5D%0A%5B%283%2C+1%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%2C+%283%2C+6%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+1%29%2C+%285%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+2%29%2C+%282%2C+5%29%5D%0A%5B%288%2C+8%29%2C+%288%2C+8%29%2C+%288%2C+9%29%2C+%288%2C+9%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+3%29%2C+%281%2C+4%29%5D%0A%5B%281%2C+2%29%2C+%281%2C+3%29%2C+%282%2C+3%29%2C+%282%2C+4%29%5D&debug=0)

It works by removing any repeated pairs first ({Q); then it compares the length of the list to the length of a dictionary created from the list (if the same x value occurs more than once, the dictionary constructor uses only the last one, resulting in the dictionary being shorter than the list)

Answer (score 2):

## PHP, 49 bytes

```
foreach($_GET as[$x,$y])($$x=$$x??$y)-$y&&die(n);
```

Prints nothing for functions and `n` for non-functions.

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6) from ETHproductions', 35 bytes

```
a=>a.some(([k,v])=>a[~k]-(a[~k]=v))
```

Answer (score 2):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), <s>30</s> <s>17</s> <s>14</s> 12 bytes

```
~.|{0=}%..|=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPmfp1r9v06vptrAtlZVT6/G9n9BaUlxraq6ulXe/@hoYwXTWAUoaaZgAiRNgGQsV3S0JZhnCCaNIGIgYUMFw1gIbQSWAPG4QOYYgrkQ08zQlChEm4LZMBFTsLyFggWQByMtoSRCp6GCMdQF6GJGUBIoAwA)

Outputs 1 for true, 0 for false.

Explanation:

```
~.|{0=}%..|= Full program, implicit input
             Stack: "[[3 5] [3 5] [6 4] [4 4]]"
~            Evaluate input
             Stack: [[3 5] [3 5] [6 4] [4 4]]
 .|          Make unique with setwise or with itself
             Stack: [[3 5] [6 4] [4 4]]
   {0=}%     Get first element of each
             Stack: [3 6 4]
        ..|  Duplicate and make unique again
             Stack: [3 6 4] [3 6 4]
           = Compare
             Stack: 1
             Implicit output
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 5 bytes

```
ĠịE€Ạ
```

Takes input as a list of keys and a list of values.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///Igoe7u10fNa15uGvB/8PL9YEsIHL//z8aCIx1FIDITEfBJFZHIdpURwGITEC8WB0uBYXoaEsdBUMdBSOQpAmqDEgIxjYEcQzhPKgGI6BesBgIQ@wCChmD1YItMkPWARZB1goWAwnDVFnoKEARSAmECXSfJZIpIATVb4zkVkO4cQhJmHxsLAA)

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 5 bytes

```
UvhÞu
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJVdmjDnnUiLCIiLCJbKDMsIDUpLCAoMywgNSksICg2LCA0KSwgKDQsIDQpXSJd)

Port of chunes' factor answer

```
U     # Uniquify
 vh   # Get the first of each
   Þu # Are they all unique?
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 3 bytes

```
EƙẠ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/12MyHuxb8P7xc/1HTGiBy//8/GgiMdRSAyExHwSRWRyHaVEcBiExAvFgdLgWF6GhLHQVDHQUjkKQJqgxICMY2BHEM4TyoBiOgXrAYCEPsAgoZg9WCLTJD1gEWQdYKFgMJw1RZ6ChAEUgJhAl0nyWSKSAE1W@M5FZDuHEISZh8bCwA)

Uses the same input format as [Dennis's solution](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/163379/85334), and does almost exactly the same thing. Considering that [`ƙ` had been implemented for half a year at that point](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jellylanguage/commit/0fe21609e36c2d25fbf8f04a7c0f03d981482457), the only conclusion I can draw is that even he couldn't remember how the damn thing works :P

Stumbled on this because I thought of [`ŒṬSṠƑ`](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///opIc71wQ/3Lng2MT/UaGH2zUfNa1x//8/GgiMdRSAyExHwSRWRyHaVEcBiExAvFgdLgWF6GhLHQVDHQUjkKQJsoxydDRIDKbMEMQxhPOgOoyAmsFiIAyxDChkDFYLtskMWQdYBFkrWAwkDFNloaMARSAlECbQgZZIpoAQVL8xkjcM4cYhJGHysbEA), which is way funnier (directly implements the classic "vertical line test") but unfortunately errors given any empty lists.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>32</s> <s>30</s> 29 bytes

Thanks [MD XF](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/61563/md-xf) for saving 2 bytes with a different approach, and [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor) for another byte with yet another approach

```python
lambda x:{*x}>dict(x).items()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZDLCoMwEEX3fsXszJRY8IkKdtkv6M5KsdVAQG3RFITSb7dJjY9SVydz79yZISw5D1VeX4sc@vi169@Hgt8E6XHPRVl3BAdxEWUnkjQlLgUfKcwMKHiKnmJGISWRVmxNZ3K@rlRtnF6O9qWSGWy9w9bOtCvYyEj6ul7p/tgZUgiVsmI082eWpDvfu@k4Cz11qfFoeSOIacGpfZZgmWiwewvqfOANjJ8Vj02MqAJxyRzzqvsPsa3Q8AE)

Prints `False` for yes, `True` for no.

```python
lambda x:not dict(x).items()^x
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZDLCoMwEEX3fsXsTCAWfKKC235Bd9YWWw0EfBSdgn9vkxqjpa5O5t65M0N4dp2bsn1UJUxp1yNU4olkoieBdTsSeptmvGM9YpbnxGcQUgaGEYNAMVAsGOQk0Yqr6a3O15WqS9eXp32pFBbf73C1s@6KDjKSoa53erh0xgxipeyYGP7MkvTNvYeOtzFQl1qvQXRIbAcuw7sGx6YW7wdQ54PoYPmsdGniRBWUbplz2Yz/IX4Umj8)

Also 30 bytes:

```python
lambda x:not x-dict(x).items()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZDLCoMwEEX3fsXszEAs@KQKbvsF3VkpthoI@Cg6Bf/eJjU@Sl2dzL1zZ4aI9DbVRfMoCxiTtiMYnVI@iY14klQ1A8OJ7lQNlGYZ8zmEyGFlxCHQDDRzDhmLjeIaeovzdZXq4vLyjK@U3BL7Ha5xll3RQUYxNPVOD@fOM4ezVnaMV/7MUvTXew8db2OgL7VevWyJ2Q5c@3cFjo2W6HrQ54NsYf6sZG4STBeIW@ZS1MN/SByFpg8)

Alternatively (thanks [xnor](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/20260/xnor)):

```python
lambda x:{*x}<=dict(x).items()
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZDLCoMwEEX3fsXszJRY8IlK3fYLurNSbDUQUFs0BaH0221S46PU1cncO3dmCEvOQ5XX1yKHPn7t@vchKfhNkB73XJR1R3AQF1F2IklT4lLwkcLMgIKn6ClmFFISacXWdCbn60rVxunlaF8qmcHWO2ztTLuCjYykr@uV7o@dIYVQKStGM39mSbrzvZuOs9BTlxqPljeCmBac2mcJlokGu7egzgfewPhZ8djEiCoQl8wxr7r/ENsKDR8)

Comment: Interesting, I did not expect `dict(x).items()` to allow set operations with a list. I think you can cut a byte with `lambda x:{*x}>dict(x).items()`.

Comment: @xnor [That prints False instead of True and vice versa](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#bZDLCoMwEEX3fsXszJRY8IkKdtkv6M5KsdVAQG3RFITSb7dJjY9SVydz79yZISw5D1VeX4sc@vi169@Hgt8E6XHPRVl3BAdxEWUnkjQlLgUfKcwMKHiKnmJGISWRVmxNZ3K@rlRtnF6O9qWSGWy9w9bOtCvYyEj6ul7p/tgZUgiVsmI082eWpDvfu@k4Cz11qfFoeSOIacGpfZZgmWiwewvqfOANjJ8Vj02MqAJxyRzzqvsPsa3Q8AE), I'm not sure if that's allowed, and `<=` doesn't save a byte

Comment: @ASCII-only I'm allowing any consistent values for the two cases, based on feedback from [this meta question](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/12305/20260).

Comment: @xnor well if `set()` is allowed as the only truthy value then I can just remove `not `

Comment: @ASCII-only No, in this spec the yes-values need to be consistent and the no-values also need to be be consistent.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, <s>39</s> <s>30</s> 29 Bytes

Thanks to [@ValueInk](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/52194/value-ink) for saving 9 bytes!

```rb
->x{Hash[x].size==(x|x).size}
```

Port of @Rod's [Python 2 answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/118977/41042).

Comment: `Hash[x]` works just as well tbh

Comment: @ValueInk thanks. Not sure why I didn't think about that.

Answer (score 1):

## [CJam](https://sourceforge.net/p/cjam), <s>14</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
_&0f=__&=
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/cjam#i@ZSUFByK81LLsnMzyu2UrIG8qOjjRVMYxWgpJmCCZA0AZKxYDlLMN8QTBrBRCFShgqGsTCWEVgawlfyyy9RSMO0xBCsBmKVGYZOhWhTMBsmYgpVYaFgAeTDSEsoiazbUMEY6kRMUSMoCZKLrf4fr2aQZhsfr2b7v1Y14T8A)

Takes input as an array of key/value pairs on the stack, returns `1` if the input is a function, and `0` if it's not.

This solution is based on the snippet `_&`, which de-duplicates an array by taking the set intersection of it with itself.  I do this twice, first on the full input (to get rid of any exactly duplicated key/value pairs) and then on just the keys (to see if there are any duplicate keys still left after the first de-duplication).

Here's the full code with comments:

```
_&           "remove duplicate key/value pairs from input";
  0f=        "remove the values, leaving only the keys";
     _       "make a copy of the array of keys";
      _&     "remove duplicate keys from the copy";
        =    "compare the de-duplicated key array with the original";
```

Comment: Just so you know, `e#` is the dedicated line comment syntax in CJam.

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 24 Bytes

```
->x{!x.uniq.uniq! &:pop}
```

Note that this only works if the points are given in `[value, key]` order, i.e. backwards. To be used like:

```
f = ->x{!x.uniq.uniq! &:pop}
p f.([[1,3], [5,2], [6,3]])
p f.([[5,3], [5,3], [4,6], [4,4]])
```

One of the funky quirks of `uniq!` is that it returns `nil` if no changes are made and the modified array if changes are made. If everything's already unique, you get a false-y value.

You asked for consistent values, so this gives a consistent `true` and `false`. If you're happy to just get a truthy value for one case and a falsey value for the other then we can save a byte by removing the first `!`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 5 bytes

```
S=ü←u
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/P9j28J5HbRNK////H61hrGOqqQMlzXRMgKQJkIwFAA)

#### Explanation

```
S=ü←u  -- example input: [(3,5),(3,5),(6,4),(4,4)]
    u  -- remove duplicates: [(3,5),(6,4),(4,4)]
S      -- is it ..
 =     -- .. equal to it
  ü    -- | remove duplicates by
   ←   -- | | first element (key): [3,6,4]
       -- | : [(3,5),(6,4),(4,4)]
       -- : 1
```

---

#### Alternative, 5 bytes

This one might be cheating, since it assumes that the pairs are ordered by their `key`s which imo would make more sense:

```
ΛË→ġ←
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zsw92P2iYdWfiobcL///@jNYx1TDV1oKSJjgmQNAOSsQA)

#### Explanation

Note that all non-zero integers in Husk are truthy:

```
ΛË→ġ←  -- example input: [(3,5),(3,5),(6,4),(4,4)]
   ġ   -- group elements by
    ←  -- | first element (key): [3,3,6,4]
       -- : [[(3,5),(3,5)],[(6,4)],[(4,4)]]
Λ      -- do all elements satisfy
 Ë     -- | all elements equal by
  →    -- | | second element (value): [[5,5],[4],[4]]
       -- : [3,2,2]
       -- : 4
```

Comment: Swapping ```ġ``` (groups elements that are adjacent) for ```k``` (groups even non-adjacent elements) avoids the ordering restriction for the second one...

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript, 41

```javascript
v=>!v.some(([a,b])=>new Map(v).get(a)!=b)
```

```js
const F = v=>!v.some(([a,b])=>new Map(v).get(a)!=b)


// Helper code to display test results on page

const $ = s => document.querySelector(s);

const displayArea = $("#displayArea");

const testFunctions = [
  [
    [3, 5],
    [3, 5],
    [6, 4],
    [4, 4]
  ],
  [
    [9, 4],
    [1, 4],
    [2, 4]
  ],
  [],
  [
    [1, 1]
  ],
  [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 1]
  ]
];
const testNotFunctions = [
  [
    [3, 1],
    [2, 5],
    [3, 6]
  ],
  [
    [1, 2],
    [2, 1],
    [5, 2],
    [1, 2],
    [2, 5]
  ],
  [
    [8, 8],
    [8, 8],
    [8, 9],
    [8, 9]
  ],
  [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [1, 4]
  ],
  [
    [1, 2],
    [1, 3],
    [2, 3],
    [2, 4]
  ]
];

function println(text) {
  displayArea.append(text);
  displayArea.append(document.createElement("br"));
}

testFunctions.forEach(value => println(JSON.stringify(value) + F(value)));

println("");

testNotFunctions.forEach(value => println(JSON.stringify(value) + F(value)));
```

```html
<div id="displayArea"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip) `-x`, 10 bytes

```
UQa#=UQaZb
```

Takes input as two command-line arguments: a key list and a value list. [Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m724ILNgWbSSboVS7IKlpSVpuharQgMTlW2BRFQSRAAqvitaKdrY2tjazNokVklHQSna1NrU2gTEgekEAA)

#### Explanation

```
UQa#=UQaZb
  a         The key list
UQ          Uniquified
   #=       Is the same length as
       a    The key list
        Z   Zipped with
         b  The value list
     UQ     Uniquified
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PowerShell](https://github.com/TryItOnline/TioSetup/wiki/Powershell) for Windows, 40 bytes

```powershell
!($args|sort -u|group{$_[0]}|? c* -gt 1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fZFLa4NAFIX3/opbmBYtI1QTQ7IIFYQuumkg3YUQrJ1Yg3HsPNqC@tvtqBMfoXQ2B@/5zp0jk9NvwvgHSdMaHWENRX1jopDFvOSUCbBlGTMq8wIddg/7qnyE6B7sWIBj1ZVh@KaBTSSYJBjMGQbPGukCw7zReaPWCFxpw9HqXgG@OcEV5lwPXJ3TxjFMua7gaOdSZTElJlmlnv4ezb1pYolhaU111eufu5XO@v/7l3AHbUgLSriFwgB1EPnJSSTIOwaUhwnj6nHQobMY4TIVanCn3sxv3dbYbbaB5IKeX95OKrv3u1XN2cooIrxdotM2@Rwu6bmEP8ksEgnNBrQ3N5ceXaESApp9ESZeqf3MVcIO6DlXma5NZVT1Lw)

Where `c*` is the shortcut for the `count` property.

Answer (score 1):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```arturo
$=>[=unique<=map unique&=>last]
```

[Try it](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?ZCVK5T)

Takes pairs in reverse order. That is, `[value,key]`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 6 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
UṬhDU⁼
```

(No ATO link since it's down at the moment)

##### Explanation

```python
UṬhDU⁼  # Implicit input
U       # Uniquify the input
 Ṭ      # Transpose it
  h     # Get the first item
   D    # Duplicate it
    U⁼  # And check if it's all unique
        # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), 27 bytes

```julia
~x=allunique(first.(x∪x))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0rPj/v67CNjEnpzQvs7A0VSMts6i4RE@j4lHHqgpNzf/KCiFFpSUZmanFXA7FGfnlCnXRGsY6CqaaOgpw2kxHwQREm4DoWIQ6S6i4IZQ2QpVHUglUYaiJyjeC6gCJcxUUZeaV5ORpaHJxKSu4JeYUo7vHEKoa5i4znKYBaVMoH0ncFFm9hY6CBUgcibaE01jMBdLGcH/ikTdC0EB1/wE)

Answer (score 0):

## C (gcc), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

*Thanks to @hvd for saving a byte!*

```
i;r,l;f(int*k,int*v){int m[10]={0};for(r=i=0;l=k[i];++i)!m[l]?m[l]=v[i]:v[i]-m[l]?++r:0;r=!r;}
```

Takes input as pointers to two zero-terminated arrays.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/c-gcc#jZLtaoMwFED/@xRpYaAzA41GTYPsQZw/CqsQtG5kmzDEZ3dJNH401k5ChPtxjsm1Z5TDihY2q7@fSyj3xmnFC1wz38vT1uto8cFtnrLUo1VaZiynrsucwzWr8le5pY2IneT2omKuy08e5emB065XpDOrbcdqLSAeGSgvv1@ZYAcQiBVBEEIgPFO@OVc/F1WBIcAqvaj45KKmsI9P70cIClvC4NjiONRaWZCEEAh8CNCWQ@XDe4a3euFAWoIMS5ANF3UDX4U3mYFmBgYzlM3@1jffZjbJoSaHBhmP/ZsXopJIXdguH2s@NvjROFqkpmsqotGP1eh3LZG2RIYlnk@B7883no@DdO2uMdbG2DAmkpVAMC1Ttyghau26Eu1KDBcZT@evJjGLyHiu4PF/S7SFGBbfmzXozg0ONYPqHzbfg1Oj9HX9Hw)

Comment: You can save a byte by turning the `m[l]` condition to `!m[l]` and swapping the other operands: you can then get rid of the parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, 55 bytes

```
i=[j[0] for j in set(input())];print len(set(i))==len(i)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#bY5BDsIgEEX3nmKWTMJCoDSthpMgS4w0DTYV4/ERWkQSXb2Z938m87q52QI7XaJTetJHA9f7ChM4Dw8biPPLMxBEc15W5wPM1pPNIyqVF4cxaiIoSKRQ2VPoMrtMc9BkLIIV8hLkLDmGZeAl3IXIwy4@5/vfZqIse@PlVhwoDFk0HCvbS4miPvgv4F@mwhs)

Comment: All you need is `i=input();print len(set(i))==len(i)`. The list comprehension is unnecessary

Comment: You have one unnecessary space, you could shorten `j[0] for` to `j[0]for`.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP, 83 Bytes

prints 1 for function and nothing for non functions

```
<?$r=[];foreach($_GET as$v)in_array($v,$r)?:$k[($r[]=$v)[0]]++;echo max($k?:[1])<2;
```

[Testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2f7df1fb3297f2487a168254bf6f3176ab2a6faa)

Answer (score 0):

## JS (ES5), 75 bytes

```
c=function (a){m={};for(i=0;i<a.length;i++)if(m[a[i]]-(m[a[i]]=i))return 1}
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Befunge-98](https://github.com/catseye/FBBI), 40 bytes

```
&:#@!#._:&:a1p1g:9`3j>;#_-3j@.1_#;$a1g1p
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/befunge-98#@69mpeygqKwXb6VmlWhYYJhuZZlgnGVnrRyva5zloGcYr2ytkmiYbljw/7@RgqECCBsDSRMgNgAA)

Input consists of zero-terminated sequence of numbers `v₁ k₁ v₂ k₂ v₃ k₃ …`, output is `0` if the sequence represents a function, `1` if not.

### Explanation

Key-value pairs are stored in the funge space on the second row (immediately below the program code).

```
&:#@!#._:&:a1p1g:9`3j>;#_-3j@.1_#;$a1g1p
&                                         S: v = read()
 :# !# _                                  if v != 0 goto N
   @ #.                                   return v
         &:a1p1g                          N: k = read(), m[10] = k, w = m[k]
                 9`3j>;#_        ;        if w > 9 goto P
        :       :        -3j   _#         if v == w goto P
                            @.1           return 1
                                  $a1g1p  P: m[v] = m[10], goto S
```

`w > 9` in the fifth line is a shortcut for `w == 32` which is the value of an uninitialized cell.

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 74 bytes

This is a lambda from `Iterable<int[]>` or `int[][]` to `int` or `Integer` (1 indicates function, 0 non-function). It checks each pair of mappings for compliance.

```java
l->{for(int[]a:l)for(int[]b:l)if(a[0]==b[0]&a[1]!=b[1])return 0;return 1;}
```

[Try It Online](https://tio.run/##XVBNa4NAED3rr5heioKR2KaBxppLodBDTznKHkazytrNKu6aEsTfbkfdJKWwzJt58/VmKzzjqm64qo7fY9NlUuSQS9QavlAo6F3HktqgISiEQgkVdYWdETIsOpUbUavwwzpvQpmUpSyAT2V4yds9CH1NQjLK1b4v6taby3An/VuQUSAKD9M1S5KM7COmEXsgN2J@y03XKljH1oniYXRi97@8cy2OcCLl3sG0QpUpA2xL7U@HOFYZcTlqriEBxX/gzk41Tt8/B/AyBHDDbQCbCTcTDsFS9GrJyOLT3yR1Rpa8TtpekzMMMRk6HDy7HfCdJMFuUbbIdQ4XbfgprDsTNnSMkcq7f2WITSMv3tzn@9O8waU3jL8)

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby 1.9+, 20 bytes

```
->a{a|a==[*Hash[a]]}
```

In recent versions of Ruby, converting an array to a hash (dictionary) and then back preserves its order, so we can do an equality comparison instead of using `.size`. Otherwise this is similar to [the more general Ruby answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/119183/6828), including the trick of removing duplicates by unioning the input array with itself.

Comment: You can also convert to hash with `to.h` method: [19 bytes](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xOrEm0dY2WitRryQ/PiO29n@BQlp0dLSxjoJprI4CnDbTUTAB0SYgOjb2PwA)

Comment: Nice! That's Ruby 2+, I think.